# Excel VBA Return Max Value of Colored Cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, background-color

I'm trying to create a function go through the sheet and return the highest value of all the green (user input color) colored cells. I'm very new to VBA and I cannot get the function to output anything besides "#VALUE!". Here is what my code looks like:

```
Function ColorMax(Color As Integer) As Single
Dim array1()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim n As Integer
n = 1
For x = 1 To 1000
    For y = 1 To 1000
        If Cells(x, y).Interior.ColorIndex = Color Then
            array1(n) = Cells(x, y).Value
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
ColorMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(array1)
End Function
```

Is there a way to fix this in order to get my desired output?

Comment: You do not set the array size so it is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not dynamic, you must set the size progamatically.

In this case there is no need for the array, it adds no benefit, just test it and replace the variable if value is larger:

```
Function ColorMax(Color As Integer) As Single

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
ColorMax = 0
With Application.Caller.Parent
    For x = 1 To 1000
        For y = 1 To 1000
            If Cells(x, y).Interior.ColorIndex = Color And .Cells(x, y).Value > ColorMax  Then
                ColorMax = .Cells(x, y).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Upvoted for the technique of referencing the worksheet with `Application.Caller.Parent`